# Render Component inside a different location

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my react app component structure

```
<App>
    <Body>
        <Top>
            ### //<- Position 1
        </Top>
        <Middle>
            <MyComponent/>
        </Middle>
    </Body>
</App>
```

I want the `<MyComponent/>` to render at `Position 1` anytime it is imported.
I have tried `ReactDom.createPortal` but i keep getting `Target container is not a DOM element`. If this is not possible how best can i achieve a similar setup.

What I have tried

```
//Top.js
<Top>
    <div id="top-render"/>
</Top>

//MyCustomElement.js
class MyCustomElement extends Component{
    render(){
        return (<div>Demo Text</div>)
    }
}

export default props => ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <MyCustomElement />,
    document.getElementById('top-render'),
);

//Middle.js
<Middle><MyCustomElement/></Middle>
```

Comment: Can you include a code example of what you've tried?

Comment: i will do that in a bit.

Comment: @HenryWoody i edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the `Target container is not a DOM element` error, because by the time execution reaches your `ReactDOM.createPortal()` call, the DOM node that `document.getElementById('top-render')` is attempting to retrieve, hasn't yet been written to the DOM.

This is because by that time, React is yet to make a successful pass through your component tree. i.e. React is yet to successfully create a virtual representation of everything in the component tree, and as a result, nothing has been written to DOM yet. So although you were expecting the `top-render` div to be there in the DOM, it hadn't actually been written yet.

The solution is to create a DOM node owned by `<MyComponent`, that will contain it's children (let's call this node `el`), then pass that DOM node, as the target DOM element in your `React.createPortal()` call (aka, it's second argument). Then when `<MyComponent>` mounts, you simply retrieve the `top-render` div and append `el` to it. Like so:

```
const MyCustomComponent = () => {
  return (<div>Demo Text: from "MyCustomComponent"</div>)
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  el = document.createElement("div");

  componentDidMount() {
    // saving this on the component so we can access it in `componentWillUnmount` later
    this.targetEl = document.getElementById("top-render");
    this.targetEl.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.targetEl.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(<MyCustomComponent />, this.el);
  }
}
```

I put together a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0w0jp87z0).

This approach works, because React guarantees that `componentDidMount()` will get  called immediately after the component is mounted (aka. written to the DOM). In other words, we know for sure that by the time `componentDidMount()` gets called, our component tree has been written to the DOM at least once, and consequently, the `top-render` div exists in the DOM.

Comment: Can you please format you code to use my component naming strategy, its a bit difficult for me to follow, with the different names.

Comment: @bubunyo sure, will do.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Anytime it is imported" ?

Anyway you can just use conditional rendering. It will do the job, but it seems your intention is something else!

```
render(){
 const { showMyComp } = this.state
 return(
   <App>
    <Body>
        <Top>
            {showMyComp && (<MyComponent />)}
        </Top>
        <Middle>
            <MyComponent/>
        </Middle>
    </Body>
   </App>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDom.createPortal` is suggested to be used on `DOM` nodes outside the scope of React App. Inside you should declare a component normally `<Top><MyComponent/></Top>`.

But for curiosity's sake, in case you want to go with this approach only, you should use the ref of the DOM node in `Top` element.

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <MyComponent/>,
    /*Ref of Container element*/,
);
```

Comment: how to i export a ref

Comment: if there's an id `top-render` you can simply use `document.getElementById("top-render")` to get the element